# topGO giving an error since upgrade to v2.40.0

Tags: r

After upgrading to R v4.0.0 I now see that my Gene Ontology enrichment code, using the topGO package (v2.40.0), fails with the error:

```
Error in if (node == GENE.ONTO.ROOT) return(2) : 
  argument is of length zero
```

The same code works fine on another machine running topGO v2.36.0 / R v3.6.3.

My minimal example is:

```
require(topGO)
require(org.Hs.eg.db)
reference = setNames(rep(0, 1000), keys(org.Hs.eg.db)[1:1000])
reference[1:50] = 1
GOdata <- new(
    "topGOdata",
    description = "Simple session", 
    ontology = "BP",
    allGenes = reference, 
    geneSel = function(set){return(set==1)},
    annot = annFUN.org, 
    mapping = "org.Hs.eg.db"
)
```

I can't find any documentation as to why this should be the case. Does anyone have any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another update has solved this issue. Comparing the sessionInfo from two similar machines with / without the second update, it appears most likely that the problem was in the GO.db package (the issue at least occurred with both org.Hs.eg.db and org.Mm.eg.db).

This R session gave the error:

```
R version 4.0.0 (2020-04-24)
Platform: x86_64-apple-darwin17.0 (64-bit)
Running under: macOS Mojave 10.14.6

Matrix products: default
BLAS:   /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.0/Resources/lib/libRblas.dylib
LAPACK: /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.0/Resources/lib/libRlapack.dylib

locale:
[1] C/UTF-8/C/C/C/C

attached base packages:
[1] stats4    parallel  stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets 
[8] methods   base     

other attached packages:
 [1] org.Hs.eg.db_3.11.0  topGO_2.40.0         SparseM_1.78        
 [4] GO.db_3.11.0         AnnotationDbi_1.50.0 IRanges_2.22.1      
 [7] S4Vectors_0.26.0     Biobase_2.48.0       graph_1.66.0        
[10] BiocGenerics_0.34.0 

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] Rcpp_1.0.4.6       matrixStats_0.56.0 lattice_0.20-41    digest_0.6.25     
 [5] grid_4.0.0         DBI_1.1.0          RSQLite_2.2.0      rlang_0.4.6       
 [9] blob_1.2.1         vctrs_0.2.4        bit64_0.9-7        bit_1.1-15.2      
[13] compiler_4.0.0     pkgconfig_2.0.3    memoise_1.1.0
```

This R session ran perfectly:

```
R version 4.0.0 (2020-04-24)
Platform: x86_64-apple-darwin17.0 (64-bit)
Running under: macOS Mojave 10.14.6

Matrix products: default
BLAS:   /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.0/Resources/lib/libRblas.dylib
LAPACK: /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.0/Resources/lib/libRlapack.dylib

locale:
[1] C/UTF-8/C/C/C/C

attached base packages:
[1] stats4    parallel  stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets 
[8] methods   base     

other attached packages:
 [1] org.Hs.eg.db_3.11.1  topGO_2.40.0         SparseM_1.78        
 [4] GO.db_3.11.1         AnnotationDbi_1.50.0 IRanges_2.22.1      
 [7] S4Vectors_0.26.0     Biobase_2.48.0       graph_1.66.0        
[10] BiocGenerics_0.34.0 

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] Rcpp_1.0.4.6       matrixStats_0.56.0 lattice_0.20-41    digest_0.6.25     
 [5] grid_4.0.0         DBI_1.1.0          RSQLite_2.2.0      rlang_0.4.6       
 [9] blob_1.2.1         vctrs_0.3.0        bit64_0.9-7        bit_1.1-15.2      
[13] compiler_4.0.0     pkgconfig_2.0.3    memoise_1.1.0
```